# ¿Como abrir una APP.jar externa con todo y recursos en Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

**Hola.**

Tengo una aplicación principal la cual funciona como launcher o lanzador de otras aplicaciones secundarias pero externas a la principal, las cuales trabajan con recursos propios. Es decir mi aplicación solo acciona estas extensiones por así decirlo que son completamente independientes de la principal y desde su directorio ejecutan y acceden a sus archivos propios. Mi código actual me permite ejecutar las aplicaciones secundarias y cargar su directorio de recurso, pero hasta ahora solo funciona en Windows:

```
File file = new File(jar); //jar es la ruta completa o absoluta al .jar
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", jar);
pb.directory(new File(file.getParent()));
try {

     Process p = pb.start();

} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Todo funciona bien hasta que pruebo en Linux (Ubuntu) y no termina ejecutando nada porque no carga los archivos de recurso y arroja una Excepción nula.

Todo por culpa de este código que es usado en dichas extensiones:

```
public ArrayList<simulador> obtener_simulaciones(String ruta) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<simulador> simulaciones = new ArrayList();

        File dir = new File(new File(".").getCanonicalPath() +"/Parametros");

        if(!ruta.isEmpty()){
            dir = new File(ruta+"/Parametros");
        }

        System.out.println("ruta dir = " + dir.getAbsolutePath() );

        for(File file : dir.listFiles()){

            simulaciones.add(obtenerSimulacion(file.getName(), 
                    leer_f(file)));

        }

        return simulaciones;
    }
```

Ejemplo de la rutas accedidas en el ubuntu, en teoría mi código Java debería hacer lo mismo que este comando, pero también el comando falla :(

> pruebas@prubas-VirtualBox:-$ cd
>   Escritorio/dist/Simulaciones/simulacion1

Una vez defina que los procesos de la consola se deben procesar en ese directorio uso el comando de Java

> $ java -jar simulacion.jar

Porque al momento de ejecutar no se que pasa pero no se recibe correctamente la ruta o sera que el archivo no se ejecuta dentro de este directorio y por eso arroja ruta errónea. Por ahora desconozco la mas probable causa no uso mucho Linux. **Muchas gracias** y espero su apoyo :)

Comment: Comparte un ejemplo con las rutas para poderte ayudar. Al parecer el problema radica ahí.

Comment: gracias, ya a coloque un pequeño ejemplo.

Comment: Disculpa pero me refería que que nos dijeras que rutas esperas y cuales estás obteniendo. Por otra parte ¿cómo procesas el parámetro 'simulación.jar'?

Comment: Amigo el código actual obtiene la ubicación en donde se situa el .jar o en otras palabras la aplicacion java. Y al obtener esta ruta debería de situarse en esta misma una carpeta llama Parametros y luego un*archivo de texto. El problema es al ejecutarse desde la consola de comando no obtiene la ruta correcta. En realidad creo que no toma en cuenta la ubicación que le doy.